# Helvetica missing font in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I have frequently found that Helvetica appears as a missing font when I open a PS file, I have Helvetica on my system so is there a way to readdress the missing fonts of a PS file to another font?

Normally I do this manually... but it will be better to have something more automatic...

It appers that "Helvetica" font does not exists on Windows Systems, just Helvetica LTD, NEUE, etc. Am I right?

Comment: I am not sure the answers properly address the *possible* situation: I myself have had inDesign claim that certain fonts are different in a document 2 months later on the exact same computer with the exact same typeface files. It would be nice to know what the root cause is.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the only way to bypass manual remappings of the font is to make sure the **exact** same copy of the font is installed on the other machine or use open type fonts.

The alternative is go to the Type -> Replace all missing fonts; however, that is often of limited functionality.

And the third alternative is to bunch select (CMD or CTRL select) with  your missing text layers in the layer panel, as they are selected you have the ability to change all of those fonts at once via the top menu. (make sure you are using the text tool)

Answer (score 1):

Just delete your old font from your system. Try downloading a new font with the same name and replace it. You can Find the fonts Ctrl Panel and Then in Fonts

Comment: What would be the correct Helvetica name? HelveticaNeue?

Comment: Helvetica Neue is the name for it.